# Lucene vs "select .. like .."

Tags: java, lucene

I am writing web application where users create content (posts on forum). Is it better to use select .. like .. or Lucene? What are advantages of Lucene in not advanced searching.

Comment: You are kind of comparing apples to oranges here. Lucene is a great tool for indexing *static* content (plain old html pages). And a database is very good for dealing with *dynamic* content (pages generated by the server-side code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't consider messing around with Lucene yourself. Instead, you should rather try stand-alone products like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) or libraries like [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html). Unfortunately, my personal favorite, [Compass](http://compass-project.org/), is abandoned now. I've tried Hibernate Search a while ago and dropped it in favor of Compass. Now, it looks as if Elastic Search is probably the easiest way to provide advanced search capabilities.

Additionally, some RDBMSs support more or less advanced fulltext search capabilities, e.g. MySQL, MS SQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is hugely more powerful/flexible, but a SELECT ... LIKE might be a good starting point. Finish your app with SELECT ... LIKE then you can add in Lucene *if you need to*, as it's a lot more work.

You might want to get your app to the point where it's sufficiently heavily used to even justify the Lucene time investment.

Short answer: SELECT ... LIKE is probably good enough to start with.

Comment: In spite of having to regenerate the Lucene's indices every time you add some new static content, I really think there is not that much work to deal with it. And, again, Lucene is good for static content; db is great for dynamic - and sometimes you need both.

Comment: I suspect Lucene is perhaps easy to use once you know what you're doing but I've always felt there's a steep learning curve to fully "getting it". I might be wrong, documentation etc these days might make getting up and running a much smoother process.

Comment: @rsenna, you dont need to regenerate the complete index, it's enough by just adding another document (key-value) representing the new data, and perhaps remove the old document.

Answer (score 1):

Leucene will likely be faster for large datasets because it can use a full text index. A `select ... like` query on a traditional relational database can typically only use an index if the the argument to `like` does not begin with a wildcard. For example:

```
select * from mytable where mycolumn like 'fred%'; -- may use an index on mycolumn

select * from mytable where mycolumn like '%fred%'; -- cannot use an index on mycolumn
```

If you need to do a lot of the second kind of query, it's unlikely to scale well. If you're using MySQL with the MyISAM table engine (default, but doesn't support foreign keys), you can use [MySQL's full text indexing capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html), but the syntax is different and MySQL-specific. It doesn't use the `like` keyword.

Comment: thanks for that example. cannot use an index in the second select is huge disadvantage.

Comment: @avv Do you have any idea why the index can't be used when querying " like '%fred%' "? The answer is that an index is, just like in a book, a sorted list of values from the indexed column(s) with a reference to the actual row in a table. It's easy to search that list for values starting with 'f'.